# Android Studio emulator stuck when booting

Tags: android, android-emulator

Today Android Studio forced me to update and the emulator stopped working. I have tried creating different virtual devices but all of them get stuck at the beginning (with the device saying "Android"). I have also deleted and downloaded the system images again, and tried deleting the .android folder.

Here are the last lines in the Android Monitor before the emulator gets stuck:

```
01-01 00:01:35.184 655-706/? E/Cryptfs: Cannot open device-mapper
01-01 00:01:35.187 655-706/? E/Cryptfs: Error opening crypto_blkdev  for ext4 inplace encrypt. err=2(No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:35.188 655-706/? D/Cryptfs: cryptfs_enable_inplace_ext4()=-2
01-01 00:01:35.188 655-706/? E/Cryptfs: Error opening crypto_blkdev  for f2fs inplace encrypt. err=2(No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:35.189 655-706/? E/Cryptfs: Failed to encrypt f2fs filesystem on /dev/block/vdc
01-01 00:01:35.189 655-706/? I/Cryptfs: Encrypted to block -1
01-01 00:01:35.189 655-706/? D/Cryptfs: cryptfs_enable_inplace_f2fs()=-2
01-01 00:01:35.189 655-706/? E/Cryptfs: Error opening crypto_blkdev  for inplace encrypt. err=2(No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:35.190 655-706/? D/Cryptfs: cryptfs_enable_inplace_full()=-2
01-01 00:01:35.190 655-706/? E/Cryptfs: cryptfs_enable: crypto block dev failure. Must reboot...
01-01 00:01:36.865 819-819/? V/DngCreator_JNI: DngCreator_nativeClassInit:
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Any solution to this in sight? I have exactly the same problem with a fresh installed Android Studio and emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Setting VM Heap to 512 MB resolved this problem for me